# Proxmox VE cluster not working

Tags: debian, proxmox

I have been using a Proxmox VE 2.0 cluster (2 servers) for months.

Today,  I had the "bright idea" to install a GUI on one of the servers. I used `tasksel`, and selected the `graphical desktop environment` (Gnome).

When I rebooted the server, neither of the servers on the cluster could see each other (shows a red light by the server on the sidebar, no statistics). The VMs on each server are working fine, individually.

`pvecm status` on the broken server shows `cman_tool: cannot open connection to cman, is it running ?`. Running it on the other server outputs a lot of lines (here: http://pastebin.com/HpQfUHTU), but I assume the important bit is

```
expected votes:2
total votes: 1
```

Trying `pvecm delnode (othernode)` on either server outputs:

```
cluster not ready - no quorum?
```

Any suggestions as to how I can fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Use `pvecm expected 1` to tell CMAN gather cluster with one node online.

Also you might want to see [Creating a Basic Cluster Configuration File](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Cluster_Administration/s1-creating-cluster-cli-CA.html)

where is described two nodes cluster configuration

Answer (score 2):

I assume, Gnome has installed it's Network Manager module and possibly changed your network configuration which could lead to a non-functional cluster.

You could check your /etc/network/interfaces file or in Proxmox at the Network Configuration.